# ROC curve - Question with exercise

Tags: self-study, classification, model-evaluation, roc

I'm studying the ROC curve theory but I'm struggling with an apparently simple exercise.
To recap what I know:
"The ROC curve is a graphical plot that illustrates the diagnostic ability of a binary classifier system as its discrimination threshold is varied. It is created by plotting the TPR (y axis) against the FPR (x axis) at various threshold settings."

$ {TPR} = \frac{TP}{TP + FN}$

$ {FPR} = \frac{FP}{FP + TN}$

#### Exercise

A binary classifier (output: positive, negative) produces a posterior probability x = P(class=positive | t) for any test instance t. The class label is obtained based on a discrimination threshold applied to x. Values above the threshold are predicted positive, values below the threshold are predicted negative.

The following plot shows how the posterior probabilities are distributed within a dataset comprised of `200` records (100 positive records, 100 negative records).

[image]

In particular, the 5 boxes in the upper part of the figure show the cumulative number of records that belong to the positive (pos) and negative (neg) classes, from $-\infty$ to the threshold defined by the respective vertical line.
For example, there are 15 positive records and 97 negative records that have $x \leq 5$.

Draw the ROC curve for this classifier.

#### Issues

I have difficulties in calculating TP, FP, TN and FN for each ground-truth bin.
For example in the first upper left bin there are 0 pos e 0 neg, but all the values have been predicted negative so should be FN = 100 and TN = 0 ? And what about positives? Could you please explain me how to get TP,FP,TN and FN values relatively to this graph?